# Best way to automate testing of AI algorithms?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm wondering how people test artificial intelligence algorithms in an automated fashion.

One example would be for the Turing Test - say there were a number of submissions for a contest.  Is there any conceivable way to score candidates in an automated fashion - other than just having humans test them out.

I've also seen some data sets (obscured images of numbers/letters, groups of photos, etc) that can be fed in and learned over time.  What good resources are out there for this.

One challenge I see: you don't want an algorithm that tailors itself to the test data over time, since you are trying to see how well it does in the general case.  Are there any techniques to ensure it doesn't do this?  Such as giving it a random test each time, or averaging its results over a bunch of random tests.

Basically, given a bunch of algorithms, I want some automated process to feed it data and see how well it "learned" it or can predict new stuff it hasn't seen yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when it comes to this sort of thing you have two datasets - one large "training set" which you use to build and tune the algorithm, and a separate smaller "probe set" that you use to evaluate its performance.

Comment: Usually you create these two sets by splitting one set into two sets.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complex topic - good AI algorithms are generally the ones which can generalize well to "unseen" data. The simplest method is to have two datasets: a training set and an evaluation set used for measuring the performances. But generally, you want to "tune" your algorithm so you may want 3 datasets, one for learning, one for tuning, and one for evaluation. What defines tuning depends on your algorithm, but a typical example is a model where you have a few hyper-parameters (for example parameters in your Bayesian prior under the Bayesian view of learning) that you would like to tune on a separate dataset. The learning procedure would already have set a value for it (or maybe you hardcoded their value), but having enough data may help so that you can tune them separately.

As for making those separate datasets, there are many ways to do so, for example by dividing the data you have available into subsets used for different purposes. There is a tradeoff to be made because you want as much data as possible for training, but you want enough data for evaluation too (assuming you are in the design phase of your new algorithm/product).

A standard method to do so in a systematic way from a known dataset is cross validation.

Comment: I added an example: I used tuning very broadly (vaguely ?), because its definition depends a lot on what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 2):

@Anon has the right of things - training and what I'll call validation sets. That noted, the bits and pieces I see about developments in this field point at two things:

1. [Bayesian Classifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier): there's something like this probably filtering your email. In short you train the algorithm to make a probabilistic decision if a particular item is part of a group or not (e.g. spam and ham).
2. Multiple Classifiers: this is the approach that the winning group involved in the Netflix challenge took, whereby it's not about optimizing one particular algorithm (e.g. Bayesian, Genetic Programming, Neural Networks, etc..) by combining several to get a better result.

As for data sets [Weka has several available](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index_datasets.html). I haven't explored other libraries for data sets, but [mloss.org](http://mloss.org/software/) appears to be a good resource. Finally data.gov offers a lot of sets that provide some interesting opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Training data sets and test sets are very common for K-means and other clustering algorithms, but to have something that's *artificially intelligent* without supervised learning (which means having a training set) you are building a "brain" so-to-speak based on:

In chess: all possible future states possible from the current gameState.

In most AI-learning (reinforcement learning) you have a problem where the "agent" is trained by doing the game over and over.  Basically you ascribe a value to every state.  Then you assign an expected value of each possible action at a state.

So say you have *S* states and *a* actions per state (although you might have more possible moves in one state, and not as many in another), then you want to figure out the most-valuable states from *s* to be in, and the most valuable actions to take.

In order to figure out the value of states and their corresponding actions, you have to iterate the game through.  Probabilistically, a certain sequence of states will lead to victory or defeat, and basically you learn which states lead to failure and are "bad states".  You also learn which ones are more likely to lead to victory, and these are subsequently "good" states.  They each get a mathematical value associated, usually as an expected reward.

Reward from second-last state to a winning state: +10
Reward if entering a losing state: -10

So the states that give negative rewards then give negative rewards backwards, to the state that called the second-last state, and then the state that called the third-last state and so-on.

Eventually, you have a mapping of expected reward based on which state you're in, and based on which action you take.  You eventually find the "optimal" sequence of steps to take.  This is often referred to as an *optimal policy*.

It is true of the converse that normal courses of actions that you are stepping-through while deriving the optimal policy are called simply *policies* and you are always implementing a certain "*policy*" with respect to [Q-Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning).

Usually the way of determining the reward is the interesting part.  Suppose I reward you for each state-transition that does not lead to failure.  Then the value of walking all the states until I terminated is however many increments I made, however many state transitions I had.

If certain states are extremely unvaluable, then loss is easy to avoid because almost all bad states are avoided.

However, you don't want to discourage discovery of new, potentially more-efficient paths that don't follow just this-one-works, so you want to reward and punish the agent in such a way as to ensure "victory" or "keeping the pole balanced" or whatever as long as possible, but you don't want to be stuck at local maxima and minima for efficiency if failure is too painful, so no new, unexplored routes will be tried. (Although there are many approaches in addition to this one).

So when you ask "how do you test AI algorithms" the best part is is that the *testing itself* is how many "algorithms" are constructed.  The algorithm is designed to test a certain course-of-action (policy).  It's much more complicated than

```
"turn left every half mile"
```

it's more like

```
"turn left every half mile if I have turned right 3 times and then turned left 2 times and had a quarter in my left pocket to pay fare... etc etc"
```

It's very precise.

So the testing is usually actually how the A.I. is being programmed.  Most models are just probabilistic representations of what is probably good and probably bad.  Calculating every possible state is easier for computers (we thought!) because they can focus on one task for very long periods of time and how much they remember is exactly how much RAM you have.  However, we learn by affecting neurons in a probabilistic manner, which is why the [memristor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristor) is such a great discovery -- it's just like a neuron!

You should look at [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network), it's mindblowing.  The first time I read about making a "brain" out of a matrix of fake-neuron synaptic connections... A brain that can "remember" basically rocked my universe.

A.I. research is mostly probabilistic because we don't know how to make "thinking" we just know how to imitate our own inner learning process of *try, try again*.

Comment: This deals more with how you'd construct a solution rather than test it, but thank you for the info.